# Does Windows Firewall fully block Windows Telemetry?

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall, telemetry

I am running Windows 10 pro. I deleted all the telemetric services and all the scheduled tasks (except defragment). With some digging I make a list of telemetric executable files and blocked them in firewall.

Is Windows firewall sufficient to block Windows telemetry fully and forever ??

Comment: no, Windows domains are allowed (hardcoded whitelist in DLLs)

Comment: You shouldn't assume that the list of exceptions you have created will not be wiped, in the future, because of a chance in a future Windows 10 feature update.  It has happened before where a feature that exists in 1703, required Microsoft to set the option to a new default value, because the previous default value was no longer valid

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Microsoft's domains are whitelisted.  You would have to block the traffic on the telemetry ports, instead of blocking, specific domains.  I suggest you block the domains using your networking hardware instead of doing anying within Windows.  Your list also will have to be updated every single time, anyone of those applications is updated, which is several times a year because a Windows Firewall exception is file version specific.

Comment: They are telling you it is due to some behind the scenes voo doo magic so leave it alone at the Windows OS level as blocking Windows OS level related objects, etc. may be superseded with funky voo doo coming to take your guns like Trump magic!! Don't do it man, don't do it, just block at a different level such as a corporate firewall as the Windows OS and blocking Windows sites, domains, etc. may not give you the expected result. I wasn't aware of the file version specific Windows FW thing as pointed out but that is even another reason it's a poor choice to maintain such access restrictions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the list of objects you have determined related to Windows telemetry and what you have setup that is blocking this. As far as **"Is Windows firewall sufficient to block Windows telemetry fully and forever ??"**... well that depends on what you do with this system as far as Windows Updates, OS version build updates, what changes are made and how those relate to explicit blocking rules you have setup, what MS does behind the scenes to allow otherwise regardless (e.g. the whitelist), and I'm sure a few other things too so you'll get an educated guess only.

Comment: Can you trust software running on an unstrusted system? You cannot. Firewalling outbound connections on the same device is meaningless.

Comment: Deleted my proposed answer, since it seems that running the FW will block entries you enter.  However, please note, that w/win7, MS added tunneling technology.  Combined with https, you can't tell what connections to MS are going through a given connection (like skype, as an example).  But since I don't see any evidence to prove they are doing that, I'm not going to claim they are.  But I wouldn't trust them.  They've indicated a willingness to deceive users before through trickery, so it would be hard to convince me they wouldn't do so again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Things to do before:** Activate Windows OS before this tweak. Gather full path of every executable files that need to be connected. Make sure to have backup. Otherwise try in virtual machine. Below I mentioned my process with batch files command. *Read also the pros and cons.*

**Procedure (with explanation):**

1. **Delete predefined firewall rules:** This command delete all predefined firewall rules. Backup the registry path `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess`. Another way is to delete those rules in Windows Firewall (WF.msc).

```
for %%X in ( 
    "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Defaults\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules"
"HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules"
"HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\RestrictedInterfaces"
"HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\RestrictedServices") do (
reg delete %%X /F
)
```

2. **Block all Outbound and Inbound connections:** This command add registry to block all outbound (DefaultOutboundAction) and inbound (DefaultInboundAction) firewall settings with batch file.

```
for %%X in (
Defaults
Parameters ) do (
 for %%Y in (
 DomainProfile
 PublicProfile
 StandardProfile ) do (
 reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\%%X\FirewallPolicy\%%Y /V "EnableFirewall" /T REG_DWORD /D "1" /F
 reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\%%X\FirewallPolicy\%%Y /V "DisableNotifications" /T REG_DWORD /D "0" /F
 reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\%%X\FirewallPolicy\%%Y /V "DefaultInboundAction" /T REG_DWORD /D "1" /F
 reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\%%X\FirewallPolicy\%%Y /V "DefaultOutboundAction" /T REG_DWORD /D "1" /F
 )
)
```

3. **Restart PC** to apply that previous registry settings. Shut down or sign out does not work.
4. **Allow apps to outbound rules:** First add *allow system* outbound rule. Then other apps including antivirus software.

   `Powershell New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "~System" -Name "~System" -Direction Outbound -Program "System" -Action Allow`
5. **Delete DNS cache service:** This command first stops and then deletes DNS caching service. As windows firewall will block svchost.exe, delete this service. Otherwise it would not be possible to enable DNS for other apps.

   `sc stop "Dnscache" & sc delete "Dnscache"`

- **Pros:** This procedure *does not require to edit hosts file*. One has not configured all the telemetry IPs and URLs in hosts file. Block entirely telemetry apps. Try this with enabling full telemetry and Cortana allowed. *Does not require to delete any other services*. No telemetry network activity has shown with [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/), [GlassWire](https://www.glasswire.com/), [tcpview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview), [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html)  and [SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) (i.e. no Microsoft web address or IP is shown).
- **Cons:** Block metro apps including Cortana, Edge, Store, Mail, Maps etc. Block any apps that want to update silently.

Comment: Find the batch file here: https://gist.github.com/Biswa96/4341e43d7a617ea212790fae8c9a22da

Comment: From Windows 10 build 17655 you should not delete the DNSCache service. The remaining procedures are same as before.

Answer (score 4):

The actual answer to your question is "Yes". See this widely mentioned article:
[Stop Windows 10 spying on you using just Windows Firewall](http://winaero.com/blog/stop-windows-10-spying-on-you-using-just-windows-firewall/).

But I would like to throw some light of sanity on this question.
The big hype of "Windows is spying on you" is sensational enough to make
good headlines, but the truth is much less interesting.

First, telemetry data is not used for commercial purposes.
Most of it is even deleted within 30 days of its transmission.

Second, Microsoft has become quite transparent about telemetry, and its
latest versions have exposed most of the functions through PC Settings
so they have become optional and controllable by the user.

Third, some parts of this telemetry data are even essential to the correct
functioning of Windows. Without these parts, for example Windows Update
may install incorrect patches with very bad results for the health of your
computer.
It is impossible to tell which "telemetric executable files"
are essential for the correct functioning of your computer.

My best advice for you is to turn off telemetry via PC Settings.
Do not give in to the hype.

As a remark: Microsoft is not the only one that is "spying" on you.
For example see [Disable NVIDIA Telemetry](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-nvidia-telemetry-windows-pc).
I really think that stopping it all is
[Cutting off the nose to spite the face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_off_the_nose_to_spite_the_face).

See also :

- [Microsoft opens up on Windows telemetry, tells us most of what data it collects](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/04/microsoft-opens-up-on-windows-telemetry-tells-us-most-of-what-data-it-collects/)
- [Microsoft : Configure Windows telemetry in your organization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-telemetry-in-your-organization)
- [Manage Windows 10 Telemetry and Data Collection settings](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-telemetry)

Comment: Care to share the source for "_First, telemetry data is not used for commercial purposes_"?

Comment: @Mohnish: The source is multiple declarations by Microsoft.